Can you visit Bermuda (Bimini) on a cruise using only a Real ID US driver's license?
I will be in Florida on short notice and noticed a very low priced cruise that I could take while there.  However, that cruise stops in Bimini and I no longer have a valid passport (mine expired and was lost years ago).
I have a valid Real ID driver's license from the state of PA.  Is this sufficient to enter Bimini and return to the ship?

In any case: You should get a new passport, at least as insurance if things go wrong (not that you will get stranded for very long time, but it can add days (or more) and expenses), and I would say: apply independently if you can use on next cruise/travel.

The title mentions both Bermuda and Bimini. Which one are you asking about? They're hundreds of miles away from each other, and Bimini is part of the Bahamas, not Bermuda.


I have a valid Real ID driver's license from the state of PA. Is this sufficient to enter Bimini and return to the ship?

No. You cannot use a US driver license to cross international borders unless it's an EDL (a different thing than Real ID). PA doesn't issue EDLs.

Are you able to bring a birth certificate?
Most cruise lines typically allow passage with a state id and birth certificate.  For example from the Carnival web site:

US-born citizens may also use a birth certificate (issued by a government agency) and accompanied by government-issued photo ID; a Mobile/Digital version of a photo ID is not an acceptable form of identification.

This is for cruises that begin and end in the US.
This policy also applies for MSC Cruises.
Typically, once you are accepted on the cruise ship no additional clearing of customs is necessary in the visited ports.  So if this cruise line allows you aboard, they will not further check your credentials in the Bahamas.
Please check with the specific cruise ship for details.

Does that cruise call in the Bahamas?

@phoog most leaving from Florida do, and it really doesn't matter where it calls.  This policy is, in general, for all cruises from and back to the US.  Not matter if the port is in Mexico, the Bahamas, Canada, Aruba or other countries.

Mexican, Bahamian, Canadian, and Aruban authorities may have different documentation requirements, however.  According to the Bahamian Department of Immigration, a passport is required, and passport cards are no longer accepted.  Presumably this also excludes the possibility of using a birth certificate and another form of ID.  No exception is mentioned for cruise passengers.  https://www.immigration.gov.bs/entry-requirements/before-your-arrival/

@phoog I'm not sure if you have been on a US cruise before, but this would not apply.  Cruisers just walk off the boat into the visiting country.  This is true for all cruise companies I have been on:  MSC, Carnival, Royal Caribbean, and NCL.  And I have only been on cruises that started and ended in the US.  The documentation provided to the ship is good enough to allow entry and some cruisers only bring birth certificates and state ids.
